# PowerShell Trying to add users to specific Database and to Roles

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script in PowerShell where I can add a number of users to a specific database and role. So, I have been trying the `Add-SqlLogin` cmdlet but it adds the users to the Security/Logins object, not the database.

So, my code is

```
Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $myInstance -LoginType "WindowsUser" -LoginName $username -DefaultDatabase $myDatabase
```

Adding the user to a specific role just returns a message saying a connection cannot be made.

```
Add-RoleMember -MemberName $username -RoleName "Developers" -Server $myInstance -Database $myDatabase
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `$username` variable contain an AD username; DOMAIN\username?

Comment: Yes, it is. What really happens is we have a CSV of users, these are checked in the script against AD before it reaches here

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and check the log files with the explorer under management.  It should show what is causing the error.